# How to load another PHP's phpmyadmin to current PHP

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

In my application there are two PHP are available.

1) PHP 5.1.6

2) PHP 5.2.6

Currently I am using PHP 5.2.6 version in my application. Also I'm using PHP 5.2.6 database ( phpmyadmin ).

Here my question is I want to use another PHP's database ( phpmyadmin ) i.e. PHP 5.1.6 's phpmyadmin.

I dont know how to do this, Please give me ur suggestions, in which file should i make change for accessing correct database in my application.

Thanks

-Pravin

Comment: Just a quick idea: run another webserver/port that's running the older php.

Comment: thanks folks for replying quickly, actually my database resides on older version, and i dont want to create database on latest version, i jst needed to hav access to db....yes it's mysql

Comment: do you have two MySQL servers running? Or are you accessing the same MySQL server from two different PhpMyAdmin versions? (check the connection config if unsure, this is a crucial difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is **not** a database, but a front-end for a [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system) like MySQL. Your scripts in PHP 5.2.6 and 5.1.6 are likely using using the same database (MySQL).